# How to track the status of threads created previously using _beginthreadex()?

Tags: multithreading, winsock2

I am working for a client-server program using C language for Windows. Here I have to create 5 threads that will run concurrently and as soon as the client is connected, the free thread among 5 will interact with client. If none-of-the 5 threads are free the client will be prompted "Server busy try later... ". AS I am the newbie for multithreading, please suggest some solutions. Thankss.
(Requirement: The threads should be created either with _beginthread() or _beginthreadex()).

Comment: is this a university assignment? otherwise it's pretty dumm to do

Comment: It is. But how to implement thread pooling in C program? Is there any need of queue?